# Change Apache .htaccess file to be used with Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm migrating a website from a server that has Apache web-server to another server that is running Nginx web-server, and I wanted to convert the .htaccess files, the problem is not just the syntax but also the file name, is it also **".*htaccess*"** or what?

Comment: Check: http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's a tool I use:

http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

It is not 100% accurate but it's pretty good base

Also, here's a link about converting the rules:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

This one can help a little:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

**EDIT:**

The file name should be `nginx.conf`

Comment: and the file is named ".htaccess" also ??

Comment: thanks on your quick reply but also I wanted to know if the file name should also be ".htaccess" or something else ?

Comment: the file will be nginx.conf, here's an example: http://brainspl.at/nginx.conf.txt but maybe you can still use the .htaccess and tell the server to use this, but because the "code" if different I would recommend to not use .htaccess to avoid confusion

Comment: Thaaaaaaaanks, can I place the file in a directory that I want to control access to it?

Comment: you mean like having multiple .htaccess in different folders?

Comment: I'm sure you can, but if you have lots of folders you might result with conflicts and that can be hard to debug

Comment: Can you tell me, where should I use of the output ? in the php file ? I used of that converter, and it gave me a output contained `if`, Now I want to know how should I use it ?

Comment: can you post some code? The php file should work, unless you have errors, check your error logs

Answer (score 23):

Nginx **does not have support for .htaccess** files.

But .htaccess files are bad. It's a way to put parts of the apache configuration erverywhere on the filesystem and to tell apache to check the filesystem at every request to see if you do not have some special configuration in place.
The only real usage of .htaccess file is to delegate a small part of the configuration to the user if you are a host provider and wanted to allow some web server configuration for your users.

Nginx configuration is compiled when nginx restart. Of course you can include several files that you can put in your web directory if you really do not care about information disclosure problems (like users seing your web server configuration), but having the same thing as a .htaccess, read each time a request is done, is not in the nginx way.

http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess:

> You can't do this. You shouldn't. If you need .htaccess, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Not a good answer — if you're using shared hosting (eg a Wordpress blog) you are just a customer; you can't recompile nginx. Yes, per-directory configuration is not a great idea, but when you're at the end of the food-chain, it's not always possible to be picky.

Comment: @PeterFlynn that's a fact, i did not wrote the Nginx documentation, and you will not have per-directory support, maybe an include of a configuration file from a server or location scope, but that may crash the Nginx process, so the host may avoid that. Seems Nginx is not made for such tasks, that's all. And if you put a .htaccess file there it will not be read by Nginx.

Comment: @regilero bingo. Nginx is not designed for shared hosting scenarios. Nor should it be: shared hosting requires each user to run their own HTTP server that gets reverse-proxied to, at least if you want any security at all.

Comment: @PeterFlynn If you are using shared hosting, then you do not care about performance or security, and can stick with Apache.  If you do care, then you will buy a VPS, which means that you have full control over the Nginx config.

Comment: @Demi Absolutely correct. But in the Real World™ the end user is not a systems engineer with the skillset to modify an Nginx config. Basically they get what they pay for :-)

Comment: @PeterFlynn Honestly VPSs from DigitalOcean are cheap.

Comment: Apache is more flexible than nginx and easier to integrate with php, django etc, easier to configure and easier to implement. Nginx scales better for websites that have a *huge* amount of traffic. For most websites Apache will do.

Comment: Please, can we avoid Apache vs Nginx comments, this question was about a fact, that response was a fact, I do prefer and use Nginx for most tasks nowadays but this wont change the `no .htaccess` fact.

Answer (score -5):

Look at here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/configuring-multiple-domains-and-subdomains-dns-nginx-issues-abound

```
server {  
    server_name  domain1.com;  
    rewrite ^(.*) http://www.domain1.com$1 permanent;  
}  

server {  
    listen 80 default_server;  
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;  
    root /home/user/www/domain1;  
    index index.php index.html index.htm;  

    server_name www.domain1.com;  

    include hhvm.conf;      
}
```

Comment: The link is to someone having an unrelated problem for which they don't have a solution.