# Revamped Joomla site to Google search engine

Tags: joomla, seo, joomla2.5

I am about to upload a revamped site of Joomla (update from 1.5 to 2.5 + changes).
I currently have a test bed sub-domain that I am currently working on. 
In few days I am about to do the swap and replace the old site with the new one.

I am worrying about Search Engines and specifically Google.
The site currently has a very good rank (appears 2nd in the search), what actions do I have to take in order to be updated and preserve the rank? (except submitting the new sitemap I guess).

It's not a difficult task but because I don't have the option to be wrong or mistakes to be done I an asking for a more "expert" advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the new site have any URL change ?

Comment: The main Url is the same but the menu has different url links than the old one.

Comment: you have to redirect all old menu urls (that are not present in new site ) to its corresponding new URLs with 301

Comment: is there any way easier way to redirect all 404 pages to my main page instead or this will mess it up? Where I have to place the redirections? Somewhere in my site or in google?

Comment: If you're doing all old urls that are not exists now to 404 you will loose its page ranks, if it is less menu url you can do it with htaccess. check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Upgraded version of the site have any URL changes like images or pages Then you have to take the things more carefully and redirect all `old URLs` to the New one with `301` redirect.
Otherwise Google will consider those pages are not exists and it will loose page rank.

Also this question is not well suits for this platform, Its better to ask on [Webmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

In this way you will not loose old page urls ranks.
For making old non-existing URLs to new corresponding url,

on your *`htaccess`* file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule your_old_url_without_domain http://www.domain.com/new_corresponding_url [R=301,L]
```

You're using `Nginx` Server so the *`htaccess`* doesn't work for try to use `Nginx` *`htaccess`* [converter](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/).

for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711678/change-apache-htaccess-file-to-be-used-with-nginx)

Hope it make sense..

Comment: Images are in the same place but menu has a whole new urls scheme. How am I going to to this for EVERY one of them :/?

Comment: is there any common standard in url change like older url is yourdomain.com/category/topic and  new one is like yourdomain.com/topic some kind of logic is there then you can do it from htaccess regular expression.

Comment: the server is not running on apache, it's on nginx and I think it does not support .htaccess files. I am not the administrator to tell for sure.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711678/change-apache-htaccess-file-to-be-used-with-nginx