# Append .html to my href

Tags: javascript, html, url, nginx, codeanywhere

This might look like a server question but I think it belongs more on SO that on SF.

Long story short, I have a Nginx server that automatically aggregates .html to my pages in the backend so that the users only see :

```
mysite.com/somepage
```

instead of

```
mysite.com/somepage.html
```

So in my code, my links look like this :

```
  <ul>
       <li class="current"><a href="somePage"></a></li>
       <li class="menu"><a href="somePage2"></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Then nginx works its magic and adds a .html to it secretly.

Of course, this doesn't work in my dev environment (environment controlled by CodeAnywhere.com) so for it to work I would have to add the extensions like so :

```
 <ul>
       <li class="current"><a href="somePage.html"></a></li>
       <li class="menu"><a href="somePage2.html"></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Since changing those href by hand everytime I want to go to production and adding back the .html when I pull the copy and want to code, there must be an easy way around this. 
Anyway I can work around that **using HTML or JS**? Or any other outside the box ideas..would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into setting up a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Are you using a webserver on your development machine?  Can you set up a URL rewrite on that server?

Comment: @Steve I can't use such a file since I'm on nginx and not apache. Altough my dev envrionment might be setted up using apache I guess I'll look into that.

Comment: @raduation I cannot. I would have to contact the codeanywhere.com support as they are managing my dev machine

Comment: @phadaphunk it looks like `.htaccess` can be converted to its nginx equivalent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711678/change-apache-htaccess-file-to-be-used-with-nginx does that help?

Comment: @Steve It is already setup on my prod envrionment using something similar to what you linked. The issue is what can I do on my dev environment to be able to live with Hrefs that do not have the .html extensions

Comment: From what it sounds like you want to do the opposite of what your question title is? Basically you want to rewrite the `foo` to `foo.html` in your ide? correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @I'L'I totally correct. I'll modify the title

Answer (score 2):

In your `codeanywhere` file explorer you can likely add rewrite directives to an `.htaccess` file:

> This info is from codeanywhere:
>
> 1. If the `.htaccess` file is not shown in File explorer you have to add your server as SFTP.
> 2. If you want to edit `.htaccess` files make sure that your server supports it and that you have right type of the server added.

In the `.htaccess` file try adding this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

That should rewrite `foo.html` to `foo`

↳ [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite) about `.htaccess` rewrite rules.

Comment: Somehow the htaccess file is ignored at runtime. I'll contact codeanywhere to know exactly how they need it setup.

Comment: Yeah probably a good idea; it seems there might be some specific details about it which their documentation doesn't contain.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a temporary `script` tag:

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  if(event.target.tagName=="A"){
    if(!event.target.href.endsWith(".html"))event.target.href+=".html";
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="something">hey</a>
```

Comment: This looks legit when I read the code but it doesn't work when I run it tho.. It simply doesnt append a .html at the end.