# Subdomain CSS-file mistakenly opens main domain css

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a site. Let's call it `mysite.com`. Not so long ago I decided that I need development version of it on subdomain. I set up everything on my VPS provider side, copied all the stuff to a new directory called `devversion.mysite.com`. If change php files in this folder, changes will appear only on `devversion.mysite.com`. Everything seemed to work, until I decided to change CSS.

If I try to open `devversion.mysite.com/internals/css/main.css` in browser, it always shows `mysite.com/internals/css/main.css` without redirection. If I open `devversion.mysite.com/internals/css/` in browser it lists everythings correctly with `main.css` size = 0Kb (it's empty, so it's correct). If I delete `main.css` from dev folder, it opens anyway from production.

Should be mentioned that I use Codeigniter 2 and have `.htaccess` file looking like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I make this css file on dev to open correctly?

Comment: where you are generating your links your css file  didn't you point to old site? I mean something like this that you saved base_url as mysite.com and when you want link to css files write something like this $base_url.'/internal.../main.css'

Comment: In html file I link them as `<link href="/internals/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and don't use `$base_url` to generate link to main.css. But even if did, it would not be opened incorrectly if use full path in browser address bar, right?

Comment: Seeing your answer I thought to give you a bit of a heads up: [please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711678/change-apache-htaccess-file-to-be-used-with-nginx). You `.htaccess` will do nothing for your providers `nginx` based server. `.htaccess` is an Apache server thing, not nginx.

Comment: @Nukeface thanks. Not very much into server-side things. Need to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

VPS provider support told me that one of `nginx` processes was down and this cause the problem. After they restarted it, everything's became OK.